# Custom Forum function not returning correct ID?

Tags: php, mysql, function, url, forum

I decided to use a forum that I made about a year ago for a website I am working on now, and everything works (after my revisions) except for after creating the topic, it does not take you to the new post. Here is the functions that is supposed to accomplish that:

```
function new_post($name) {
    $sqlpost = "SELECT `id` FROM `forum_question` WHERE `name`='$name' ORDER BY `datetime`     ASC LIMIT 1";
    $mysqlpost = mysql_query($sqlpost);
    return $mysqlpost;
}
```

And here is how I apply that: `<a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo new_post($name); ?>">View Post</a>` (Keep in mind that `$name` is defined earlier in the document)

This is the URL it takes me to, after creating a post: `http://localhost/Nu-Bio/view_topic.php?id=Resource%20id%20#10`

Thanks for reading and I hope you can help. ALSO: I know that I should be using MySQLi. I will be updating once I get the next few things I want to finish done~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return Values for result_query()

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

```
<?php

 function new_post($name) {
  $id = 0;
  $sqlpost = "SELECT id FROM forum_question WHERE name='".$name."' ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1";
  $mysqlpost = mysql_query($sqlpost);
  if (!$mysqlpost) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else
  {
     $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlpost);

      $id = $array['id'];
  }
  return $id;
 }

?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Okay, I did what you said and it worked. (Also my database was messed up, so that took some messing around with.) Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

it's been a long time since i've used mysql_query(), but I believe you're returning an array. Try this instead.

```
return $mysqlpost['id'];
```

Comment: That seemed to just turn the url into `blahblah.php?id=`, but thanks anyway.

Comment: have you checked your query in phpmyadmin to see that it's returning the ID?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function new_post($name) {
$sqlpost = "SELECT `id` FROM `forum_question` WHERE `name`='$name' ORDER BY `datetime`     ASC LIMIT 1";
$mysqlpost = mysql_query($sqlpost);
return $mysqlpost;
}
```

and then check this

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($mysqlpost);echo '</pre>';
```

OR you can do also this

```
function new_post($name) {
    $sqlpost = "SELECT `id` FROM `forum_question` WHERE `name`='$name' ORDER BY `datetime`     ASC LIMIT 1";
    $mysqlpost = mysql_query($sqlpost);
    return $mysqlpost['id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add mysql_fetch_assoc,
you can try this:

```
$mysqlpost = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlpost));
return $mysqlpost['id'];`
```